# screencapture as a service doesn't work in OS X 10.9.2

Tags: macos, automator, screen-capture

I have updated to 10.9.2 and looks like it has broken my image uploading script.

It starts with a shell command:

```
screencapture -i /tmp/last_screen.png
```

It should take a picture of selected area. It works well when I type it in console, or when I press "run" in Automator to test my service. 
But it doesn't work when I try to run it as service or via hotkey - my cursor doesn't change to area select tool.

Added: even "take screenshot" action in automator is no longer working

Comment: I wonder if this is a sandbox requirement to prevent snooping by using this method to automate capturing the screen if other options than -i were passed to the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is something strange, I just rebooted and everything is fine now.